# Qt: How to shift the cursor focus to a field in a Find dialog box/tool once it's shown?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, focus, text-editor

I'm working on a text editor project, and the Find tool currently looks like this when launched:

[image]

I'm wondering how I could shift the application/text cursor focus so it goes within the "Find what" field automatically as soon as I `show` the dialog box (which is of type `QDialog`).

Currently, as you can see, the text cursor remains within the document, so the user has to manually click on the Find tool to start searching, which is a bit iconvenient. I tried messing around with the `setFocus` method of my dialog box, but that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: To what action does the QDialog open?, You could show the code of how to access the dialog.

Comment: Sure! I'll create a Github repo and push my local changes there and then mention the relevant files and code.

Comment: [Here's the relevant code](https://github.com/AleksandrHovhannisyan/User-Friendly-Text-Editor/blob/master/CustomTextEditor/mainwindow.cpp#L304) that triggers the QDialog to appear. More specifically, it's a custom QDialog class that I defined [here](https://github.com/AleksandrHovhannisyan/User-Friendly-Text-Editor/tree/master/CustomTextEditor) under finddialog.h and finddialog.cpp. Please let me know if you'd prefer I paste the code here directly instead of linking to it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To activate the focus in the QDialog do the following:

```
void MainWindow::on_actionFind_triggered()
{
    if(findDialog->isHidden())
    {
        findDialog->show();
        findDialog->activateWindow();
        findDialog->raise();
        findDialog->setFocus();
    }
}
```

But by default the one that will take the focus will be the QPushButton, so to change that behavior it must be established as a QDialog proxy to the QLineEdit.

```
lineEdit = new QLineEdit();
setFocusProxy(lineEdit); // <---
```